# Xcode imageset aspect ratio

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, imageset

In any imageset we have 3 options for iPhone resolutions: @1x, @2x and @3x. The issue I am facing is that both iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X use @3x images, however the screen of iPhone 8 Plus (and below) have aspect ratio of 9:16, however X (and above) have aspect ratio of 207:448.

I therefore have to do aspect-fill on "lower-end" iPhones, which results in cutting sometimes significant parts of an image, which looks ugly. I don't have an option to change the assets, so any advice is welcome.

Tried image slicing. The result is even worse. Shuffling images programmatically is also not an option since the asset in question is a launch screen.

The target iOS version is 9, if this matters.

Comment: You can use different sizes for your UIImageView depending on the device. Will that help?

Comment: In the `XCAssets` part, you can chose the `Scales`: `Individual and Singles Scales` `Width Class` & `Height Class` if that can help to device more your assets.

Comment: *"I don't have an option to change the assets"* --- sounds like some better advance planning would have helped. You may need to use `Aspect Fit` and set the background to a fitting "letter box" color (such as black). In general, your app should get to its first screen as quickly as possible --- so a "complex / detailed" launch screen is ill-advised.